# Golang gRPC context to check if cancelled or if deadline is exceeded while running function code

Tags: performance, go, concurrency

I am writing a gRPC Golang application and am looking for the best way to check if the deadline is exceeded or if the client cancelled the call.

On the server side I created a channel called `done`. When `done` is called by either the go-routines the server returns with either the error or the success.

In the code I have two go-routines. The first one runs the actual program and if successful calls the `done` channel without and error, the second waits for the `context.Done()` and if called calls the `done` channel with the error.

I am wanting to know if there is a more efficient way to do this without two go-routines.

I don't want to check periodically `ctx.Done()` or `ctx.Cancelled` because I feel that would be a waste of time but the method below would use more CPU resources.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"

    "google.golang.org/grpc/codes"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/status"

    pb "mygit/controller/pb"
)

// ping controller
func (s *server) PingController(ctx context.Context, in *pb.PingControllerRequest) (*pb.PingControllerResponse, error) {

    done := make(chan error) // make a done bool
    var retOut pb.PingControllerResponse

    // run function in go routine and call done when finished without being cancelled
    go func(i *pb.PingControllerRequest) {
        log.Println(in.Client)
        // other business logic would go here
        retOut = pb.PingControllerResponse{Pong: "PONG"}
        done <- nil
    }(in)

    // if context is done (due to error) return with done
    go func(c context.Context) {
        <-c.Done()
        done <- status.Error(codes.Canceled, c.Err().Error())
    }(ctx)

    // wait for done channel to be called
    var doneErr = <-done

    // if there was a context error return with error
    if doneErr != nil {
        return nil, doneErr
    }

    // no context error return with response
    return &retOut, nil
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.